# SQL LIKE and NOT LIKE in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 100 tables. Some of the tables contain table name as 'plan_2' and some of them 'temp'.

So how can I select tables only 'plan_2' not containing 'temp'.

My query not working.

```
$result=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'plan_2%' AND TABLES  NOT LIKE '%temp%'");
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_name LIKE '%plan_2%'
and table_name NOT LIKE '%temp%'
```